# Why don't setup kube-dns in PAI k8s cluster?

Tags: kubeflow, openpai

I tried to deploy kubeflow in the clusters and found there was no dns service available. I am not sure the reason, could someone explain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to minimize the dependency. PAI doesn’t need dns. You can add dns service to k8s deployment yourself.